# Rollback says “resetting any offensive votes”, but rolls back *all* votes.

Tags: bug, reputation, editing, votes

The rollback button of a question says that it will reset any *offensive votes*, which presumably means down-votes. Yet, rolling back to an earlier revision seems to reset up-votes (and accompanying reputation) as well.

Is that a bug or a poorly written label?

Comment: On which question did you notice this behavior, please?

Comment: Voting to close. We can always reopen, but given the continued development that took place in the last 10+ months...

Comment: Jarrod, I don't remember. Daniel, wouldn't most questions on Meta then qualify as too localized, especially once they are addressed?